# MySQL JOIN with expressions

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables. One contains offers with amount of items, and second contains allocations of items to offers. I am trying to write a query that produces table showing offered amount of items and total allocated amount, per offer.

Sample table `offers`:

```
+----+----+----+
|oid |uid |amt |
+----+----+----+
|   1| 413|  10|
|   2| 297|   7|
+----+----+----+
```

Sample table `allocations`:

```
+----+----+------+
|aid |oid |alloc |
+----+----+------+
|   1|   2|     4|
|   2|   2|     2|
+----+----+------+
```

I want the following result:

```
+----+----+------+
|oid |amt |alloc |
+----+----+------+
|   1|  10|     0|
|   2|   7|     6|
+----+----+------+
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT `offers`.`oid`, `offers`.`amt`, COALESCE(SUM(`allocations`.`alloc`),0)
FROM `offers`
LEFT JOIN `allocations` ON `allocations`.`oid`=`offers`.`oid`
```

However, the sum works on the whole table, not just entries that satisfy

```
`allocations`.`oid`=`offers`.`oid`
```

and offers that have no allocations don't get printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **GROUP BY**.

```
SELECT `offers`.`oid`, `offers`.`amt`, COALESCE(SUM(`allocations`.`alloc`),0)
FROM `offers`
LEFT JOIN `allocations` ON `allocations`.`oid`=`offers`.`oid`
GROUP BY offers.oid
```

(I assume `offers.oid` is your primary key?)

Strictly speaking, it should be

```
GROUP BY offers.oid, offers.amt
```

which is to say any column not the result of an aggregate function must be listed in the `GROUP BY` clause. Some servers are configured to enforce this, while some aren't.

Comment: And then you migrate the code to a mysql server with strict sql mode enabled and will wonder why your code stopped working...

Comment: @Shadow Fixed it. Happy now?

Answer (score 0):

Any aggregate function, such as sum() will operate in the entire resultset, unless you provide a group by clause.

```
SELECT `offers`.`oid`, `offers`.`amt`, COALESCE(SUM(`allocations`.`alloc`),0)
FROM `offers`
LEFT JOIN `allocations` ON `allocations`.`oid`=`offers`.`oid`
GROUP BY `offers`.`oid`, `offers`.`amt`
```

However, I do not get the 'offers that do not have allocations do not get printed' part, since the left join should take care of that, unless in your real query the order of the 2 tables are reversed.

Answer (score 0):

So here you have to use group by clause to do sum for each oid...

```
  SELECT `offers`.`oid`, `offers`.`amt`, COALESCE(SUM(`allocations`.`alloc`),0) FROM `offers`
LEFT JOIN `allocations` ON `allocations`.`oid`=`offers`.`oid` group by oid
```